# iOS: UIImage and other items in prototype UITableViewCell not showing consistently

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have properly connected a UIImageView to a prototype cell as a weak IBOutlet but I can't have it shown on both the simulator and device when I run the program.Things get even more weird when I try to delete the prototype cell and rebuild it back, but have other items (e.g.:UIButtons,UILabels) not showing up.

Tried "clean", "clean build folder", deleted the app from my device, and even deleted the "derived data" folder from my mac but to no avail. Even tried fitting in a new UILabel to the cell and have it not showing up!

I have made sure that:

1. The items are properly connected to my cell .h file as weak, nonatomic IBOulets as the following:

   `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *coverImage;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *activityLabel;`
2. The cellForRowAtIndexPath is properly done:

{

```
NewsFeedCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsFeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (self.dataInStorage)
{
    NSDictionary * newsFeedData = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.dataInStorage];
    NSDictionary * dataToDisplay = [[newsFeedData objectForKey:@"Content"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //ActivityLabel
    NSInteger typeID = [[dataToDisplay objectForKey:@"TypeID"] integerValue];
    switch (typeID)
    {
        case 3:
            cell.activityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"created an event - %@", [dataToDisplay objectForKey:@"Title"]];
            break;

        case 7:
            cell.activityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"added a listing - %@", [dataToDisplay objectForKey:@"Title"]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //CoverImage
    UIImage * coverImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[dataToDisplay objectForKey:@"CoverImage"]];

    CGImageRef cgref = [coverImage CGImage];
    CIImage *cim = [coverImage CIImage];

    if (!(cim == nil && cgref == NULL))
    {
        //Image is available
        cell.coverImage.image =[UIImage imageWithData:coverImage];
    }

}

return cell;
```

I think the problem maybe in the config or storyboard settings, though I can't figure out still after more than 10 hours. Anyone needing the source code to take a look, please let me know so that I can send you the whole folder.

Need help!

Comment: attach a screenshot please.

Comment: please provide the code in cellForRowAtIndexpath 
And check if you have connected the delegate and the datasource of the tableview with your controller

Comment: please provide source code..

Comment: @LightYagami I have checked and they are properly connected. All the other items in the cell is showing, so should be an indication that the data source and delegates are well connected. Just that things get real strange for the UIImageView and when I try to edit the existing items.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Which screenshot would you need?

Comment: I want to show you NewsFeedCell code.

Comment: @DipenChudasama I have edited some of my codes above. Do you need the whole folder of source codes? How can I send them to you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as i can understand, 
cell.coverImage.image =[UIImage imageWithData:coverImage];
coverImage is a UIImage
Try cell.coverImage.image = coverImage

Comment: Put your code in drop box and provide me link of that/ or put it in your gitHub and provide me link.

Comment: @DipenChudasama Link to my files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v1prxriqd7pcsws/AABbjYCPwlTMfzgY4Y2xh-PJa?dl=0 Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LightYagami I have tried that as well. No avail. Perhaps you can look at my source codes provided in the dropbox link above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: name of the class please

Comment: @LightYagami Sorry, I didn't get you. What do you mean by "name of the class"?

Comment: the name of the class of the above problem, the class where dis problem occured..

Comment: @LightYagami Sorry I left that out. The cell class involved is the "NewsFeedCell" and the tableViewController class involved (data source and delegate) is "NewsFeedPageTableViewController"

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of UIImageView in Identity Inspector (present in right side of Xcode).

Sometimes its **(width,height)** becomes **(0,0)** automatically.

Comment: Have checked and they are fine. I'm using auto layout so the width and height are fixed. Could it possibly change at run-time?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Xcode 6.1. So have you figured out any workaround to solve this issue? My whole storyboard just turned so strange and I'm totally worried of how I'm gonna code my remaining >5 tableViews.

Comment: @Marcus same problem has occurred with me while working with UITableView.. the view used shirk to top left corner and its width and height became 0,0

Comment: So what did you do? Programmatically reset the width and height to the desired amount at cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Marcus ya.. i do hard coded.. programmatically set the width n height.. so whenever i run the application, it does change at runtime

Comment: I have NSLogged the frame size of the imageView and it is 0.0 for both height and width, just like what you've suggested. So I tried to make a new frame and assign it to the imageView. But still it is not visible. Could it be any special way that I should hard code the frame?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found what i think is the fault here.
Disconnect the Cover image outlet connection, 
Create a new ImageView and drop it in the storyboard. Create the connection with the class and the outlet. That should do it.

It seems you have copy pasted the outlets from another view, Please disconnect all connections and reconnect them with your class (newsFeedcell) and the outlets in the storyboard once again. Doing this will prevent future conflicts.

Cheers, Hope this solves it

[EDIT]

write this code.

```
cell.imageview.image = coverimage
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have tried disconnecting the coverImage outlet connection in the right panel connection inspector, deleting the imageView, dragging a new imageView to the prototype cell and connecting it to the @property of the cell .h class. Still no results. Have also disconnect all IBOutlet connections and reconnect them back. Still the imageView is still not visible.

Comment: Wow. The "cell.imageView.image = coverImage" solves the problem! Would you mind telling me what is the reason behind this? How would the "cell.coverImage" be referenced by "cell.imageView" instead? What had gone wrong in my code and what should I do to prevent future mistakes? Thanks!

Comment: well what i think is that, you copied the outlets from some other view and that messed up the outlets and 
in your code coverimage was an UIImage instance. and first you assigned cell.coverimage.image to a nsdata instance(i think).
And check the outlet once again if cell's coverimage is connected as cell's imageview. 
if that helped please accept the answer

Comment: I tried reconnecting everything but nothing works besides adding the "cell.imageView.image = coverImage" code. Thanks for the solution. However, I checked the documentation and I suspect "cell.imageView" is a default property of UITableViewCell, and it would not be a wise solution to assign a pic to it, especially given that I'm going to add in another imageView to the cell later. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So I guess the problem is still not totally solved. Thanks a lot for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Gotten an answer from @Paulw11 after posting the question in another thread. Apparently I had mistakenly added in items into the cell when my size is configured to reg-reg, instead of the usual any-any I use. Certainly, those items will not be visible on my iPhone device! (reg-reg will make those items visible only on iPad devices) Future coders beware!

Thanks again to @Paulw11 for the great help. And also @LightYagami and @AashishTamsya for the effort.

Cheers!

Link to the other thread: [iOS: Items in custom UITableViewCell not showing up consistently. Storyboard bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917476/ios-items-in-custom-uitableviewcell-not-showing-up-consistently-storyboard-bug/27918868#27918868)